# readthedocs custom subdomain point from godaddy not working

Tags: subdomain, read-the-docs, godaddy-api

Could someone helps?
It seems everything is correct setting.
I have point my subdomain from readthedocs project as below.

```
Type   Name    Value   TTL Actions
CNAME   docs    webpres.readthedocs.io. 1 Hour
```

**NOTED.** Here is godaddy domain hosting.
My hostname **docs.webpres.org**
and **webpres.readthedocs.io** is the readthedocs theme Short URLs.

Could anyone have a look if found any wrong with my set up

Regard
Rony

Comment: Just confirmed what i have done is corrected and works now. To clarified this config dns must be followed godaddy name server not readthedocs. Just keep this information in case someone needs.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the correct way to set up the DNS CNAME record is pointing it to `readthedocs.io` instead of `<slug>.readthedocs.io`. Check the documentation about this https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom-domains.html#adding-a-custom-domain